# Is the Firestore collection write limit (imposed by sequentially-updated indexed fields) affected by collection-group queries?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

From how I understand it, if a collection has a monotonically-increasing indexed field, a write limit is imposed on that collection. If that collection is split into two separate collections, each collection would have its own write limit. However, if we split that collection into two separate collections but give them the same name (putting them under different documents), would they still have their own independent write limits if the monotonically-indexed field was part of a collection-group query that queried them both together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not the way it works.  A collection group query [requires its own index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#queries_supported_by_collection_group_indexes), and the limit you're talking about is the write rate of the *index itself*, not the collection.  Each collection automatically indexes fields from documents for just that specific collection, but that would not apply the collection group queries that span collections.

Note that the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) states the limit as:

> Maximum write rate to a collection in which documents contain sequential values **in an indexed field**

On a related note, [disabling the indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#remove_indexes) for a specific field on a collection allows you to bypass the normal monotonic write limits for that one field on that collection because it's no longer being indexed.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices says "the maximum write rate to the collection is 500 writes per second" if the indexed field is sequential. Doesn't this mean the write rate limit is on the collection itself and all writes, even writes to non-indexed fields, are subject to failure if this limit is reached?

Comment: It's not the collection, it's the index.  A collection doesn't really *do* anything other than organize documents for later querying.  It doesn't have any properties or behaviors.  The behavior is all about the index.

Comment: That makes sense and, actually, that way of explaining it makes more sense to me than the documentation. In conclusion, only an index, whether it's single collection or collection-group, that includes a field that updates sequentially is prone to imposing a write limit on that index, right?

Comment: Yes, and only when that field is present, else it does not touch the index